# .ajax or .load() causing: "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

When a user clicks on various links to other places in my app (I do not know which links before hand), I want to load the result of those links into a specific div. I have tried using .load() and also .ajax() for this, but each time I get the warning:"Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience."

I have seen various SO answers on this, but none of them solve the problem. This seems strange, as .load() is supposed to be asynchronous automatically, and when I try .ajax() I expressly set async to true.

What should I do to stop this warning from occurring?

Example with load:

load.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
  $('#click_button').click(function() {
   var path = $(location).attr('pathname');
   $('#my_div').load(path);
  });
});
```

Example with $ajax:

load.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
  $('#click_button').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: $(location).attr('pathname'),
      async: true,
      success: function(path) {   
       $('#my_div').html(path);
      }
   });
 }); });
```

Both of these work, but get the "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest"... warning.

Comment: My guess is  something else is causing said warning.